# What is the terminology of "drain cover"?

Tags: terminology

I want to find a more professional word for "drain cover" as illustrated below. What is this called by the workers or manufactuers?

[image]

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_cover)

> A drain cover is a cover with holes in it or a grating used to cover a
>   water drain. It allows the drainage but in the same time it prevents
>   bigger objects to be flushed in the drain.

Comment: What do you want to know?  What is confusing you?

Comment: Maybe it's the word **manhole cover** that you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhole_cover

Comment: A _drain cover_ can be very small, like what you might find in a bathtub or a washroom sink. But your picture shows the cover of a [_storm drain_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_drain).

Comment: @Jasper Nothing confuses me, I just want to find a more professional word. Maybe the question should be "what is it called by the workers or manufactuers?"

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, no, they are different things.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin -- A manhole is large enough for a man to go through.  A handhole is large enough for him to put his hand into the hole.

Comment: The photo shows a **cast iron storm grate**.

Comment: @J.R. That depends where you are from, the picture is from the U.K. and I would call it a drain cover, definitely not a storm drain.

Comment: @JamesP - I didn't say it was a storm drain, I said it was "the cover of a storm drain". As for the UK/NoAm variants, those are listed in the Wikipedia article I linked to in my initial comment, so I didn't see the need to delve into it any further. (Moreover, the OP's picture looks quite similar to the one provided in that article.)

Comment: I meant storm drain cover. I was only commenting as you made it sound as though drain cover was the incorrect term. (BTW the pic is from here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/16498755@N07/32461457161 )

Comment: @JamesP - Nope, I was just pointing out that drain covers come in all sorts of shapes and sizes, from heavy, industrial-grade storm drain covers to [ones designed for household use](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1qEVsSFXXXXXoaXXXq6xXFXXX3/304-Stainless-Steel-Kitchen-Sink-Stopper-Drain-Cover-Strainer-Basin-Sink-Plug-Water-Rubber-Sink-Filter.jpg_640x640.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Drain cover"* is formal and professional.  You might also call it a *grating* or a *grate*. If you wanted to be precise "cast iron storm drain grate".

There is variation between British and American English. The term "storm drain" is more common in American English. So "Storm drain cover".  You might also note that there is quite a lot of variation in the actual design, according to how much rainfall occurs in a particular location.